# Is it sensible to run Backbone on both server (Node.js and Rails) and client for complex validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, backbone.js

This is verbose, I apologise if it’s not in accordance with local custom.

I’m writing a web replacement for a Windows application used to move firefighters around between fire stations to fill skill requirements, enter sick leave, withdraw firetrucks from service, and so on. Rails was the desired back-end, but I quickly realised I needed a client-side framework and chose Backbone.js.

Only one user will be on it at a time, so I don’t have to consider keeping clients in sync.

I’ve implemented most of the application and it’s working well. I’ve been avoiding facing a significant shortcoming, though: server-side validations. I have various client-side procedures ensuring that invalid updates can’t be made through the interface; for instance, the user can’t move someone who isn’t working today to another station. But nothing is stopping a malicious user from creating a record outside of the UI and saving it to the server, hence the need for server-side validation.

The client loads receives all of today’s relevant records and processes them. When a new record is created, it’s sent to the server, and processed on the client if it saved successfully.

The process of determining who is working today is complex: someone could be scheduled to work, but have gone on holidays, but then been called in, but then been sent home sick. Untangling all this on the server (*on each load*?!) in Ruby/Rails seems an unfortunate duplication of business logic. It would also have significant overhead in a specific case involving calculating who is to be temporarily promoted to a higher rank based on station shortages and union rules, it could mean reloading and processing almost all today’s data, over and over as each promotion is performed.

So, I thought, I have all this Backbone infrastructure that’s building an object model and constraining what models can be created, why not also use it on the server side?

Here is my uncertainty:

Should I abandon Rails and just use Node.js or some other way of running Backbone on the server?

Or can I run Node.js alongside Rails? When a user opens the application, I could feed the same data to the browser and Node, and Rails would check with the server-side Backbone to make sure the proposed new object was valid before saving it and returning it to the browser.

One factory is how deeply Rails is entrenched in this application. There isn’t that much server-side Ruby for creation/deletion of changes, but I made a sort of adaptation layer for loading the data to compensate for the legacy database model. Rails is mostly just serving JSON, and CSS, Javascript, and template assets. I do have a lot of Cucumber features, but maybe only the data-creation ones would need to be updated?

Whew! So, I’m looking for reassurance: is it reasonable, like suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8307526/760389), to be running both Rails and Node on the server, with some kind of [inter-process communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352786/how-to-structure-communication-between-nodejs-server-and-rails)? Or has Rails’s usefulness shrunk so much (it *is* pretty much a single-page application like mentioned [in that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8307526/760389)) that I should just get rid of it entirely and suffer some rewriting to a Node environment?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you're worried a lot about [concurrency](http://www.slideshare.net/pgriess/nodejs-concurrency) as much as being able to do push data, which both platforms are completely capable of performing. If you have a big investment in Ruby code now, and no one is complaining about its use then what might be the concern? If you just want to use Node for push and singularity of using javascript through the stack then it might be worth it to move code over to it. From your comments, I really feel it is more about what is interesting to you, but you'll have to support the language(s) of choice.  If you're the only one on the team then its pretty easy to just slip into a refactor to node just because it is interesting. Just goes back to who's complaining more, you or the customer. So to summarize: Node lets you move toward a single language in your code base, but you have to worry about what pitfalls javascript on the server has currently. Ruby on Rails is nice because you have all the ability to quickly generate features and proto them out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was feeling a bit insecure about choosing to run Node alongside Rails because it doesn’t seem widely-discussed. Your suggestion that it’s about what’s interesting helps. I think I should leave the Rails part because I have other things to work on. But can you give me an idea about what you mean by the “pitfalls javascript [has] on the server”?

Comment: I should word that better, Ruby has its performance issues on servers as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629784/how-is-node-js-inherently-faster-when-it-still-relies-on-threads-internally